# How can I filter all except requests app engine dev console in web.xml

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, servlet-filters, web.xml

I want to filter all requests to my jersey servlet so I do this:

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Unfortunatly, this has the side-effect of catching the dev console (http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin)

Is there a way I can exclude paths matching "/_ah/*" from the filter?

Or perhaps a better way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125296/can-i-exclude-some-concrete-urls-from-url-pattern-inside-filter-mapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion by @adarshr I started to look into extending the Jersey filter servlet so that I could skip certain paths. It was then I realised that it already supports paths to ignore as an init param.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
    <param-value>/(js|css|(WEB-INF/jsp)|_ah)/.*</param-value>
</init-param>
```

(I was already even using it after pasting in the code from somewhere without reading it!)

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to have a servlet which you can use to configure all the filter mappings. So servlet would handle all the queries and reroute them accordingly, as web.xml doesn't allow regex mapping.

We use guiceServlet from Google Guice to do the same thing:

Then in `configureServlets` we do the following:

```
  serveRegex("/(?!_ah).*").with(JerseyGateway.class);
```

There are a number of suggestions on the topic you can look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857279/google-guice-on-google-appengine-mapping-with-working-ah).